# How to test if a new record has been created using FactoryGirl in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

How do I write a test for `User.find_user_id` class method using FactoryGirl?

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   def self.find_user_id (name)
     result = User.find_or_create_by(name: name)
    return result.id
   end
end
```

Edit: I didn't make myself clear the first time. All I want in the test is that when I call `User.find_user_id` the line `User.find_or_create_by` is hit.

I used `expect(User).to received(:find_or_create_by)` but that will make `result = nil` and the return statement `return result.id` will cause an error of `undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass`. I was thinking of using FactoryGirl to create a new record so I wouldn't get this error message. But I'm not sure if this is the right approach as I am new to RSpec/Rails

Comment: You should clarify what you want to test first. In your situation, if you want to test a new record is created, then you should think about `how to test the changes of database`. If you want to test what returns from the method, think in another way. Refer to `factory-bot`'s document + google before start a new question.

Comment: Why are you testing that `FactoryBot` (formerly `FactoryGirl`) works? They have their own testing. The title of the question does not line up with the body since you are actually asking how to test your `User#find_user_id` method which has nothing to do with `FactoryBot` at all

Answer (score 2):

you can use [valid?](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#valid-questionmark-and-invalid-questionmark) in rails model to check factoryGirl `create` function in your model specs

```
RSpec.describe User, :type => :model do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  it { is_expected.to be_valid }
end
```

Comment: This does not answer the question "How do I write a test for User.find_user_id class method using FactoryGirl?"

Comment: This `let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }` is the answer to my problem! I couldn't figure out how to test when the name doesn't exist in the db. Using your `let` I was able to have `allow(User).to receive(:find_or_create_by).and_return(user)` and I didn't get the `undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass`. I hope I did it right. Thank you very much for answering a vague question that I didn't really know how to ask in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

1.You will need factory of `User` model as below :

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name: 'Stefen'
  end
end
```

2.As your class method `find_user_id` returns an id of user whose `name` is passed to that method. So, specs can be written as below :

```
describe '.find_user_id' do

  before do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end

  it 'should find user id by name' do
    find_user_id(@user.name).should eq @user.id
  end

end
```

3.In rspec, it should verify that your class method `find_user_id` returns an `id`

Comment: While this answer may be correct, leaving some explanation would improve this question in a long run.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback mike.

Answer (score 1):

`FactoryBot` (note that `FactoryGirl` was [renamed a couple of weeks ago](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/factory_bot)) has a build in linter to ensure that all factories generate valid instances. See [Linting Factories](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/c58f893c0c31344a4340be0b82ff95a9d4ccabe9/GETTING_STARTED.md#linting-factories) in their documentation.

A very simple example how to use the linter might look like this:

```
# spec factory_linter_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

Rspec.describe 'FactoryBot' do
  it 'creates valid instances' do
    FactoryBot.lint
  end
end
```